# Stack Overflow on IIS 6.0

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, iis-6

I am using WAMP as localhost on my pc, and upload all data to the hosting (using IIS 6.0).
I am using [lightbox gallery](http://wordpressgogo.com/development/lightbox-gallery.html) in one post, and in the sidebar, to show recent photos from that gallery (on the sidebar).
my code on the sidebar as follows:

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery id="66" size="large" columns="4" num="12" pagenavi="0"]');
```

this works great on my WAMP, but causing stack overflow on the hosting...
when I leave it on the sidebar just as

```
[gallery]
```

it works (but showing the photos from the current page... so it's not really working. Actually the only thing seems to cause this problem is `id="66"` which call the photos from post id 66.

Comment: I read the title and assumed it was something about hosting the StackOverflow.com software on IIS 6.0.  Maybe you could put the word "Error" in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your code like this, maybe it will work...

```
$gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="66" size="large" columns="4" num="12" pagenavi="0"]';
print apply_filters( 'the_content', $gallery_shortcode );
```